# Answer Google account disambiguation permanently

Tags: youtube, google-workspace, google-account

This is the message that Google gives whenever we sign in to YouTube. We know how this happened. Now we want to choose Business account forever instead of each time we sign in.

[image: There are two existing Google Accounts for xxx@xxx.com. Which account do you want to use?]

How do we choose Business Account and then have Google remember our answer forever?

**Edit:** Add the "Learn More" info. It explains how we created the conflicting account and not how to resolve the situation.

[image: Learn more...]

**Edit:** Add the result of choosing "Individual Account:"

[image: The result of choosing "Individual Account."]

What is a `gtempaccount.com` email address?

I am not able to recover the account because I do not:

1. know its password,
2. have access to a `gtempaccount.com` address,
3. know any information about that account's creation.

Comment: What happened when you clicked the 'Learn more' link and followed the directions? At some point you should be given the option to either rename one of the accounts, or copy / import the data from one to another. The options vary depending on the conflicting Google service.

Comment: @Folk I added the result of clicking learn more.

Comment: @Folk The directions show nothing about next steps.

Comment: See [Resolve conflicting accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/185186?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén It says, "If you've already created the user's Google Account, the next time that user signs in to a consumer product, they'll be asked to change their account." I have not been asked to change the account. That might be because I do not know that password for the temp account and cannot sign in to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose "Individual Google Account" and then change the email address for that account. For details see the related official help article [Change your username](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/19870?hl=en)

If you need to **recover your individual account's password**, follow these steps.

1. Click "Individual Google Account."
2. Click "Forgot Password."
3. Indicate that you do not know your most previous password.
4. Request a recovery email to the `admin%shaunluttin.com@gtempaccount` email.
5. Login to `admin@shaunluttin.com` to receive that email.

Then continue with the renaming process.

Comment: Hmm. In my question, I mentioned, "Now we want to choose Business account forever..." Will your answer let that happen?

Comment: Since you have two Google accounts with the same email address, yes, changing the email address of one of the accounts will solve "the problem".

Comment: Okay. I tried this. It needs a different password than my business account password. I didn't know the password, nor do I have access to the recovery email: admin%shaunluttin.com@gtempaccount.com

Comment: I'm glad to see that you updated your question and that updated my answer :)